# How to return data from inside of addOnSuccessListener{} method in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to get user data from `Firebase` `Firestore` database ,
I am intended to get info of user who is currently logged in.
Now for make this information accessible from other Classes I created  get method for username and email,

when I used get method from Another class , I got an `indexOutOfBoundsException`  with index 0,size 0.
It looks like my array in global scope is not getting data when i called `array.add()` method from `addOnSuccessListener` method.

```
package com.example.myapplication.utils

import android.os.Build
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import com.example.myapplication.models.User
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore

class UserInfo {
private val list = ArrayList<User>()
private val mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()


private fun getCurrentUserId(): String {
    val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    var currentUserID = ""

    if (currentUser != null) {
        currentUserID = currentUser.uid
    }
    return currentUserID
}


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
fun getUsername(): String {
    getCurrentUser()
    return list[0].userName
}


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
fun getEmail(): String {
    getCurrentUser()
    return list[0].email
}


@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
private fun getCurrentUser() {
    mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS)
        .document(getCurrentUserId())
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            val user = document.toObject(User::class.java)
            if (user != null) {
                list.add(user)
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            TODO()
        }
}
```

}

Comment: before `list.add(user)` in addOnSuccessListener{} I have  `list.clear()` in my code ,

Comment: There is no way you can do that. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using either `callbackFlows` or `RxJava`. I prefer `callbackFlows`.

```
//This Needs to be a suspending function
    private suspend fun getCurrentUser() = callbackFlow<User>{
        firestore.collection(Constants.USERS)
            .document(getCurrentUserId())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                val user = document.toObject(User::class.java)
                if (user != null) {
                    list.add(user)
                    //Sends the data on cold Flow or Channel Flow
                    trySend(user)
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                TODO()
            }
        
        awaitClose {
         // suspends the current coroutine until the channel is either closed or canceled and invokes the given block before resuming the coroutine.
      }
    }
```

`trySend` is where you send the data.

Also, `awaitClose` is required.

Furthermore, from wherever you call this function, you need to `collect` it, or else it won't work `cold flows` require an active collector to work.

You can do this by simply,

```
private suspend fun collectCurrentUser() {
  getCurrentUser().collect { data->
    // Use Data
  }
}
```

You can follow the following documentation:
https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow

Comment: Seems like this would be a better candidate for a coroutine as it only emits a single value?

Comment: Well Yes, if we follow the above code we are emitting only one value and the ```channelFlow``` . But the ```channelFlow``` will keep running and occupy memory until the collector is removed. So, we also need to remove the collector. Well that's my understanding since callbackflows are pretty new.

Comment: do i need any dependencies for using this flow ? because my IDE is not recognising callbackFlow ,it prompts "create function callbackFlow()"

Comment: Well try these:
``` implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.1' ```
``` implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.1' ```
I believe they come in coroutines libraries

Comment: This is inappropriate use of `callbackFlow`, which is intended for callbacks that are called repeatedly. Callbacks that are called once should be converted to suspend functions (`suspendCancellableCoroutine`) instead of Flows.

Comment: I am wondering why list.add(user) didnt worked in this case , My list never got any data .I didn't understand why?@Tenfour04

Answer (score 1):

You can use Kotlin Unit function to return list

```
 private fun getCurrentUser(listener:(ArrayList<User>())->Unit){
       mFireStore.collection(Constants.USERS)
           .document(getCurrentUserId())
           .get()
           .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
              val user = document.toObject(User::class.java)
              if (user != null) {
                  list.add(user)
                 }
              listener.invoke(list)
             }
          .addOnFailureListener {
              TODO()
            }
    }
```

Now you can this method as below

```
getCurrentUser(){list->

}
```

Comment: i copy pasted this code and it showed me alots of errors and redlines

Comment: So neat and clean! Thank you for adding this response!

Comment: @roshannepal_x   
what problem are you facing?

Comment: @Lena Glad it helped you.